# Como comparar SUM com outro campo numérico?

Tags: sql, sql-server, script

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma tabela *SB2010* onde tenho a quantidade atual do produto em estoque e tenho a tabela *SB8010* onde tenho a quantidade do produto separado por lotes.
Preciso verificar se há alguma divergência entre a quantidade atual e a soma da quantidade na tabela de lotes.
Criei um *script*, porém aparecem dados onde mesmo igual, é acusado como diferente.
Alguém teria alguma ideia de como resolver?

```
SELECT B8_FILIAL, 
       B8_PRODUTO, 
       B8_LOCAL, 
       SUM(B8_SALDO) AS Total_B8, 
       B2_QATU FROM SB8010 AS SB8
INNER JOIN SB2010 AS SB2 
 ON (SB8.B8_FILIAL = SB2.B2_FILIAL 
     AND SB8.B8_PRODUTO = SB2.B2_COD 
     AND SB8.B8_LOCAL = SB2.B2_LOCAL)
WHERE SB8.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
  AND SB2.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
GROUP BY B8_FILIAL, B8_PRODUTO, B8_LOCAL, B2_QATU
HAVING B2_QATU <> SUM(B8_SALDO);
```

[image: Resultado da execução do script]

Neste caso, conforme observado, a consulta acima deveria trazer 0 registros, visto que não há divergências entre os valores.

Obs: Campo *Total_SB8* é o somatório da quantidade por lotes do produto (neste caso, não interessam os lotes, somente o somatório da quantidade total)
Campo *B2_QATU* é a quantidade atual do produto

Comment: HAVING B2_QATU <> Total_B8;

Comment: @MarcosMarques dessa forma acaba dando coluna inválida.

Comment: Esquisito, tenta transformar os 2, vê se da certo. HAVING cast(sum(B2_QATU) as numeric(9,4)) <> cast(sum(Total_B8) as numeric(9,4))

Comment: Como é a tipagem (casas decimais) destes campo ? Estranho demais.

Comment: @MarcosMarques Erro de estouro aritmético ao converter float no tipo de dados numeric.

Comment: @Motta ambos são Float

Comment: HAVING cast(sum(B2_QATU) as float) <> cast(sum(Total_B8) as float). Tenta colocar os 2 para float então. Só para garantir a integridade dos tipos. Fiquei muito curioso com esse seu caso.

Comment: @MarcosMarques Trouxe diversos registros com as 2 colunas iguais. Estava com 4 registros (conforme print enviado) e com este comando ficou 377 registros

Comment: Sem ter acesso a base é complicado, desculpe. Mas tenta agora. HAVING sum(cast(B2_QATU as float )) <> cast(sum(Total_B8) as float). Colocando a trasnformação na coluna, antes de aplicar a função agregada.

Comment: Deve resolver assim `ROUND(B2_QATU,4) <> ROUND(SUM(B8_SALDO),4)`.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling Deu certo, muito obrigado